# Parsing HTML tags using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to python. I want to store each HTML tag into item of list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = """
 <body>
    <div class="product">
    <div class="x">orange</div>
    <div class="x">apple</div>
    <p> This is text </p>
    </div>
</body>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

y=[]
for i in (soup.find_all("div", class_="product")):
   y.append(i.get_text().encode("utf-8").strip())
```

From the above code the length of y is 1 and store all text on one item of list. However,it is necessary to parse using "div product" and store each text inside html tag into different item to list.

So the y will be :

```
y =['orange', 'apple', 'This is text']
```

instead of :

```
 y=['orange\napple\n This is text']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `text` if all you wanted was the directly contained string, and ask only for elements contained in the `div.product` tag:

```
for elem in soup.select("div.product *"):
    y.append(elem.string.strip().encode('utf8'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> y = []
>>> for elem in soup.select("div.product *"):
...     y.append(elem.string.strip().encode('utf8'))
... 
>>> y
['orange', 'apple', 'This is text']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
soup.find_all("div",class_="product")
```

gives all the div tags with class product so u have a list now. So when u run the for loop it iterates only once and gives the complete text in div tag.

So to get data of every child use something like this

```
for child in soup.find_all("div", class_="product").findChildren():
         y.append(child.string.strip().encode('utf8'))
```